# Apply parameters of a function to another without entering everything manually

Tags: python, class, user-interface, tkinter

I'm making an app as a beginner and I wanted to know if you could make an object (like a Button) and it will show up in every window (sry if that doesn't really make sense I'm not a fluent english speaker)

For example:

```
from tkinter import *

base_window = Tk()
base_window.title('First Window')
base_window.geometry('500x500')

def Button_to_go_to_2nd_window():
     base_window.destroy()
     2nd_window.title('2nd Window')
     
Button = Button(base_window, text='Go to 2nd window', command=Button_to_go_to_2nd_window)

menubar = Menu(base_window)
filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff = 0)
filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=window_base.destroy)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Quit", menu=filemenu)
window_base.config(menu=menubar)

tkinter.mainloop()
```

How can I apply the parameters of the first function (like geometry as well as the exit button) without having to enter everything again manually ?
I thought about making a window class but I dont know how to apply it to the other function within the class

Comment: Not really sure what you are trying to do here. A widget is always a child of another widget, in this case the button is a child of base_window. When you destroy base_window the button will be destroyed along with it. Or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: Post what you have tried on using class.